# mysqld how to only listen on unix socket?

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-8.0

how do i make mysqld not use ip at all, only listening on an unix socket? if i do

```
mysqld  --socket=mysql.sock
```

it still opens port 3306, and if i do

```
mysqld --bind-address='' --socket=mysql.sock
```

it complains

```
2023-03-14T00:51:56.041113Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013203] [Server] Invalid value for command line option bind-addresses: ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit configuration file (my.ini) and add `--skip-networking=ON` into `[mysqld]` section (by default it is commented, so uncomment it and add `ON` value). Or add this option to the service starting command line.

[skip-networking system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking)

> This variable controls whether the server permits TCP/IP connections. By default, it is disabled (permit TCP connections). If enabled, the server permits only local (non-TCP/IP) connections and all interaction with mysqld must be made using named pipes or shared memory (on Windows) or Unix socket files (on Unix). This option is highly recommended for systems where only local clients are permitted.